# Mootools: How to change css class if following conditions is meet

Tags: forms, mootools

I want to change the labels class to "labelDeactivated" if the textarea is unfocused and got more than 10 chars in it. How do I make that happen? Tryed a couple of solutions but no luck :-(.
BTW if conditions isn't meet it should turn back to label.

```
<p class="label">Your review</p>
<textarea id="review" name="review"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kkgp2/

```
var headline = $$('.headline');
var headlineLabel = $$('.headlineLabel');
var headlineNote = $$('.headlineNote');

// Change label //
headline.addEvent('blur', function(){
    headlineNote.fade('hide');
    if (this.value.length>10) {
        headlineLabel.addClass('labelDone');
    }
    else{
        headlineLabel.removeClass('labelDone');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/7SmwU/

```
document.id("review").addEvents({
    keyup: function() {
        if (this.get("value").trim().length >= 10)
            this.getPrevious().addClass("labelDeactivated");
        else
            this.getPrevious().removeClass("labelDeactivated");
    }
});
```

btw, use `<label for='review'>your review</label>` - better semantic markup and accessibility.